# Updating junit gives compilation error at @Rule and TestName

Tags: java, maven, junit, junit4, rule

Have been using `@Rule` from `junit` using `4.12`. But today updated to 4.5

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Getting error on compiling the code on

```
@Rule
public TestName name = new TestName();
```

> package org.junit.rules does not exist
>
> cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol:   class Rule [ERROR] location: package org.junit

Has this been removed? Any alternatives to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving from version `4.12` to `4.5` feels more like downgrading than updating.

`@Rule` was introduced in `4.7` version of `junit`, thus it cannot be found.

Now the most stable version of `junit` is `4.12`, at least this is the latest one that you could find in [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit). However, [junit5](http://junit.org/junit5/) was introduced on 7.7.2016 and you could use it if you apply this dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit5-api</artifactId>
   <version>5.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: my bad, just assumed `4.12` something like `4.1.2`